# Angular: How do you associate a controller and a DOM element explicitly

Tags: angularjs

I have a DOM element that I want to associate with a controller, the usual way of course is using ng-controller. But in this case I cannot do this (for reasons that will take too long to explain).

Is there a way to do this association manually?

e.g.

```
<div id="foo">
...
</div>

angular
    .module('APP', [])
    .controller('FooCtrl', function ($scope) { 
        ...
    });

var $ele = $('#foo');
angular.bootstrap($ele, ['APP']);
// somehow associate #foo with FooCtrl without using ng-controller="FooCtrl"
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: can you modify the html or not ?

Comment: yes, I can modify the html

Comment: but you can't just add `ng-controller="FooCtrl"`?

Comment: We need to understand **why** you can't just add it I'm afraid, else we don't know what **you** can or can not do

Comment: Right, I will try to explain. In our app we build everything using components. A component is a piece of html + JS that is self contained. Components can be nested. The JS for a component is loading dynamically using require JS. Say, you have a top component with a nested one, Angular tries to bootstrap the top component but sees ng-controller for the nested one, but it cannot find the code for that nested component. I hope that this is somehow clear, I might need to build a JS fiddle to explain this better.

Comment: you can probably use a directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with a [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

```
angular.module('APP').directive('fooCtrl', function () {
  return {
    controller: 'Foo'
  };
});
```

then in your HTML

```
<div id="foo" foo-ctrl>
```